# dumpsys output format

Tags: android, adb

Is the format of the dumpsys output exactly the same for each android device? As in is it safe to read the output of the dump service in an app and perform exact string matching to parse the data returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not expect the format to be 100% the same. There were slight changes between the different Android versions. Also some services are dependent on specific hardware components used (radio/chipset/peripherals/sensors/etc) - so actual service code might come from different OEMs rather than from Google.

But 98% might be just enough for your application.

Answer (score 0):

No, to my knowledge you should always get the same output from the same device running the same OS though.

From my experience there aren't too many output formats. I have only experienced 2 across the several dozen devices I write monkeyrunner tests with. I use a simple try except to cover reading both of the formats I have encountered. If they both fail, then I print an error and stop my script.

```
memList = memFull.split()
try:
    dalvikIndex = memList.index('dalvik')
    heapSize = memList [dalvikIndex + 5]
    memAllocated = memList [dalvikIndex + 10]
    memFree = memList [dalvikIndex + 15]
except ValueError:
    try:
        dalvikIndex = memList.index('Dalvik')
        heapSize = memList [dalvikIndex + 4]
        memAllocated = memList [dalvikIndex + 5]
        memFree = memList [dalvikIndex + 6]
    except ValueError:
        print 'Unsupported output format detected. MemoryMonitor script will need to be updated to support this format'
        break
```